# Php7.2-fpm.sock not created on reboot. Restarting php7.2-fpm doesn not work properly on raspberrypi with nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a webserver on my raspberryPI to run laravel application. I installed php7.2 and nginx. Everything was working well, I was able to see default Laravel page on my computer, so the webserver worked. Unfortunately, after rebooting raspberry the file `php7.2-fpm.sock` is not created and running `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` does not work. It doesnt show any errors, just freezes and I have to click ctrl+c. What is interesting, after a while the above command starts working, the file `php7.2-fpm.sock` is created and the server works. How can I fix this bug? I need webserver to start automatically after booting raspberryPI.

My /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file:

```
listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

Comment: How about `sudo service php7.2-fpm start`?

Comment: you can switch from using *.sock files to using local network, i.e. listen on `127.0.0.1:3000` or something

Comment: `sudo service php7.2-fpm start` also freezes and I have to ctrl+c it. :(

Comment: I tried to switch to local network, but it still doesnt work after booting and I cannot run `sudo service php7.2-fpm start` or `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` . It seems like problem with php7.2-fpm but I am not able to solve it